# Error running Gradle [Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration]

Tags: gradle, flutter, dart, build.gradle

I try to run my Flutter project but I get this error

I using `Flutter 1.7.8`
And in `pubspec.yml` I add these dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  http: ^0.12.0
  sqflite: ^1.1.6
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
```

And when I try To run I get blow error, how i can fix theme?

```
Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/home/zagros/Projects/flutter/flutter-example/news/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :path_provider

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'.
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.2/builder-3.1.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
  Command: /home/zagros/Projects/flutter/flutter-example/news/android/gradlew app:properties
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem

First I downgrade Flutter SDK form `1.7.8+hotfix.4` to `1.7.8+hotfix.3` after that change dependencies `sqflite: ^1.1.6` to `sqflite: ^1.1.0` and finally set up a high-quality VPN connection.

And the error is fixed and Gradle builds successfully.

Comment: Hi. Can I ask, what VPN did you use? Hotspot shield, windscribe and vpn gate are not working now.